# Xcode hangs for 12 sec when running

Tags: xcode

When I run my app in Xcode it sometimes (about 50% of the times) hangs for about 12 seconds before it starts to run. The applicationDidFinishLaunching happens as normal and the app screen appears, but Xcode does not pass control to it for about 12 seconds. You can see this behavior on Youtube at
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RNgUnZMaAM

Has anyone experienced anything like it or have any idea what it could be caused by. I'm running Xcode 6.3.1 on OS X 10.10.1.

I've looked in the console and the only difference from when things work is the following output, that I get when things are not working.

```
6/5/15 8:08:14.006 PM Xcode[1122]: [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7703/IDEKit/Workspace/IDEToolbarStopButtonViewController.m:259
Details:  Stop Button failed to cancel tracker: 
     <IDEExecutionOperationTracker 0x7fc44f6a7e40 Run "Start" isFinished: YES>
     canceled: Hard Cancel
              <IDEExecutionRunnableTracker 0x7fc44f4bd7e0 (null) isFinished: YES>
         canceled: Hard Cancel
         is _finishedRunning
     operationFinished: YES
         <DVTOperationGroup 0x7fc452915600 not blocking>         suboperations:
              <IDEBuildOperationGroup 0x7fc452b9d9d0 not blocking>             suboperations:
                  <IDEBuildOperation 0x7fc44b701570 not blocking>
                  <DVTOperation 0x7fc452b99e40 not blocking>

              <DVTOperationGroup 0x7fc452ac8d60 not blocking>             suboperations:
                  <DVTOperationGroup 0x7fc44dcf09d0 not blocking>                 suboperations:
                      <DVTOperation 0x7fc44f6a3680 not blocking>
                      <IDERunOperation 0x7fc44f4049e0 not blocking>
                      <IDESchemeActionResultOperation 0x7fc44f46c810 not blocking>

                  <DVTOperation 0x7fc44f6a9120 not blocking>


Object:   <IDEToolbarStopButtonViewController: 0x7fc44b7de8a0>
Method:   -_stopLaunchSession:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc44b503200>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

Comment: `Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.` So do that and move on, I'd suggest. This has nothing to do with your app; it's just Xcode acting up.

Comment: Thanks matt, but it must be something in my project, since if I create a totally empty Cocoa project with nothing in it,  the bug never happens. I will start from my project and eliminate part by part until the wrong behavior disappears and see if I can ring in the culprit.